# Sorting of ArrayList shows first item twice

Tags: android, sorting

i try to Sort my arrayList depending on the distance between user and the location. To do this i created the following two methods:

```
   private void getDistanceBetweenUserAndMarket(ArrayList<SellerObject> seller) {

    for (int  i = 0; i<seller.size(); i++) {
        SellerObject se = seller.get(i);
        Location storeLoc = new Location("");

        storeLoc.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(se.getLat()));
        storeLoc.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(se.getLng()));
        if (storeLoc != null && mlastLocation != null) {
            Float distanceInMetres = mlastLocation.distanceTo(storeLoc);
            Float distanceInKm = distanceInMetres / 1000;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            se.setDistance(distanceInKm);
            seller.set(i, se);
        }
    }

    sortArrayList(seller);
}

private void sortArrayList(ArrayList<SellerObject> seller) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        seller.sort(Comparator.comparing(SellerObject::getDistance));
    }
    getProducts(seller);
}
```

the duplicates were created by the last method. Also a strange phenomen is that sometimes the highest value is at the top sometimes the lowest. I would like to have the lowest value at the top

Comment: Can you share your SellerObject code, as maybe the updates to instances of this class are causing your issues? You also shouldn't need to call the line seller.set(i,se) since you're putting the same instance you read from the list.

Comment: it was a different mistake. But thanks for your help